# Why doesn't my box-shadow overlap correctly on these flex children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, z-index

So basically the design of the page should look like this:

[image]

And when I try to implement through HTML and CSS:

[image]

as you can see here the Navbar's box shadow overlaps the header.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: ##f3f3f3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.main-container-right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

#main-nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 0;
}
#header {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 1;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <nav id="main-nav">
  </nav>
  <div class="main-container-right">
    <header id="header">
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add z-index and positioning the elements, it didn't seem to work. Is there any fix for it?

Here is the problem in a CodePen: https://codepen.io/biljx/pen/rNzwwqd

**EDIT: I couldn't fix the z-index problem but managed to get shadow like the original design by using `drop-shadow` instead of `box-shadown`  `filter: drop-shadow(0px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) );`**

```css
#main-nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);*/
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) ); 
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not really how box shadow works. It's not a true 3D thing. There's zero gap between layers in a document, so shadow won't vary.

Comment: I just tried `box-shadow` and `z-index` and the element that is put later in the DOM or has heigher `z-index` overlaps the shadow of the other element, so the problem is not with CSS, it could be you giving a higher `z-index` to a parent of both elements, or giving position `sticky`, `fixed` or `absolute` to the one with shadow with automatically puts it on top of other elements, if there is no z-index defined.

Comment: try `position:absolute`

Comment: Seems to be a unique/reproducible issue with box-shadow on flex children. I can't figure out what is preventing the children from behaving properly even when removing the extra child wrapper.

Comment: @TylerH I made the shadow work using `drop-shadow` but still cant figure out the problem of `z-index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out why all these manipulations with *z-index*? The blocks are already in the correct order. But, as long as you have a transparent `#header`, the shadow of `#main-nav` will be visible. So just add a background color for the `#header`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.main-container-right {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}

#main-nav {
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px 10px #0004;
}

#header {
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #0004;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <nav id="main-nav">
  </nav>
  <div class="main-container-right">
    <header id="header">
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution. Looks beautiful!